# How to handle orientation change in iPad in an effective way?

Tags: ipad, orientation

I am developing an application in ipad and i need to make it in a way that it support the landscape and portrait orientations. I think we need to override some methods of **UIViewController** class and perfrom the orientation ,view resize, view positioning etc. Can anyone help me by providing your valuable suggessions in this?

Thanks,
Ajith

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the 'Handling View Rotations' section of the [UIViewController's class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

If you have, can you give a more specific situation you're having trouble with?